# Pair of simultaneous equation involving 3 unlike terms.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve these two equations using elimination:

$$\begin{cases}
\\12x^2-4xy+11y^2=64
\\16x^2-9xy+11y^2= 78
\end{cases}$$

I have already tried converting them to fractions to get 2 like terms but it failed.
Any ideas on how to eliminate 2 unlike terms together?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hints: $78(12x^2-4xy+11y^2)-64(16x^2-9xy+11y^2)=0$ and $y=0$ is not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Subtracting yields $4x^2+5xy=12$. Eliminating the mixed term yields $4x^2+5y^2=24$.  Multiply the first equation by $-2$ and add that equation to the latter. Then factor.